# Windows VM on XEN --> ZFS possible?

Tags: linux, windows, xen, zfs

I am running Debian Jessie with XEN installed.

All configuration files for VMs etc.. is all stored on a ZFS pool.

I am just wondering if anyone can confirm if it is possible to install a windows VM? IF so, is there any guides?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference that would make running a Win VM in that setup impossible if you can run other types of VMs (i.e., your basic setup is working).

As for the second part, any requests for guides, tutorials etc. are [off-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).